# How to create arrays in SQL Server table cell

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, database

I am looking for way to store a sequence of items in a single column.

Relational databases are designed specifically to store one value per row / column combination. In order to store more than one value, but I don't like to serialize a  list into a single value for storage, then deserialize it upon retrieval.

Please let me know any approach available to store a sequence of items in a single column.

Even i dont like to create another table to store that list, but this is exactly what relational databases.

I am looking for something like this

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/collection-data-types/

Thanks in advance

Ranjith Murthy

Comment: As you say this is probably best avoided.  But if you feel the trade offs are worth it you could use a column of type XML.  This would allow you to load your list in a structured format that can be queried later.

Comment: Plain and simple: **Don't do it**. Stop wasting your time on trying to do this - it's a horribly bad design idea and violates even the **first normal form** of database design. **DON'T DO IT!** If you need to store n values - use table rows - that's how relational databases handle multiple values.$

Comment: ^^^ what @marc_s said ^^^

Comment: Its against the 1NF (first normal form!)